# Jack Moore zoom() script and How to change img src for multiple images on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs with this structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="zoom">
        <img src="http://mywebsite.net/images/products/small/image1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The js part is:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
  $(".zoom").zoom({
    url: 'big/image1.jpg',
    on: 'mouseover'
  });
});
```

On hover on the .zoom div I would like the script to load img from the src:
http://mywebsite.net/images/products/big/image1.jpg

As you can see the only difference is that `small` becomes `big` in the url.

How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript to this:

```
$(".zoom").each(function(arg, el){
    var image = $(el).find("img");
    $(el).zoom({
        on: 'mouseover',
        url: image.attr("src").replace("small", "big")
    });
});
```

Comment: Arg0n thank you for helping me. Your script changes the img src to big but zoom() is not being activated.. Any ideas why? No errors in the console

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? I'm not familiar with `.zoom()`

Comment: I'm getting `.zoom() is not a function` in your fiddle, missed some required js?

Comment: also this is his official site: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ but could not succeed to make it work as on examples..

Comment: @Europeuser I think i got it working as intended. See updated code and fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96265/discussion-between-arg0n-and-europeuser).

Comment: You are my hero :) Thank you so much ! Working as charm !